# Combining 2 named ranges into a single series line chart in Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, charts, date-time

How do I combine 2 named ranges into a single series. I have months on the X axis and average hours per month YTD on the Y axis. I want to separate the average hours into financial years i.e. the average hours value does not link between the last month of one financial year and the succeeding month commencing the next financial year.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add a column to the data source that extracts the month name, for example

=TEXT(A2,"mmm")

Then you can build a pivot table. Group the dates by year and place the years in the columns, put the months in the rows and total the values.

A line chart from that series has separate lines for each year.

[image]

Edit:
If the time line continues on the X axis and you want a gap in the line, then you will need to start a new series. With a line chart this could look like this:

[image]

Using a Scatter chart, the data can be in the same column in the source table:

[image]

Comment: Hi teylyn. Thanks for your reply. The ideal solution I'm looking for is to be able to insert a physical break in the series between months of Jun and Jul to indicate a new Financial Year without adding additional series.

Comment: I don't understand what you want to achieve. Please mock up something with the drawing tools and update your question.

Comment: Hi teylyn, I've added a mock-up above. Hope this helps.

Comment: I've added solutions for the scenario.

Comment: Hi teylyn, Thanks again. I was hoping that by applying specific Range Names to the data series I might be able to achieve the result you have without having to add a new series. Would this work?

Comment: If you want to see gaps, you will need to use different series. Whether or not the series refer to range names versus cell references does not make that different.